# Authentication failed for user @domain.com - Capistrano & Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I am trying to set up Capistrano to deploy a website on a remote server. When I run the following command:

```
cap production deploy
```

I get the following error:

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host domain.com: Authentication failed for user @domain.com
```

Here is my **deploy.rb** file in the config directory of my Rails app:

```
...

set :application, 'my-app'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:karns/my-app.git'
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/my-app"

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git
set :branch, 'master'
set :user, "deploy"
set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, "production"
set :deploy_via, :copy
server "domain.com", roles: [:app, :web, :db], :primary => true

...
```

To my understanding, deploy is supposed to be the user on the remote server.

What am I missing? Why does the error say "Authentication failed for user @domain.com"? Why wouldn't it say "deploy@domain.com"? If you need any other code, please let me know.

Comment: I suggest to use IP address instead domain name, something like this

server '111.34.12.1', user: 'your_server_uname', roles: [:app, :web, :db], my_property: :my_value

Comment: I'm having the same issue - was working yesterday, but not today

Comment: Solution for me was to add my ssh key as the ssh config seems to be ignored.  ssh-add -l will list all keys and then ssh-add <key_file_to_add>

Comment: Am i right in thinking the user is the one on the server ? Do i need to generate a key for that user or can i connect with my other user account?

Comment: @TrevTheDev - If I created deploy as my user on my remote server, how do I set the keys up?

Comment: Also note how it says authentication failed for *user* @domain.com - why would it say user? Shouldn't it say *deploy*?

Comment: @karns if you have create a "deploy" key [often stored in home/your_username/.ssh] the you would do "ssh-add ~/.ssh/deploy"